# is there a .net library like the Find and Replace tags feature of Expression Web

Tags: html, text, replace, ide

Microsoft FrontPage and it's successor Expression Web have a feature in the Find and Replace dialog that allows you to find a tag by name, and do various actions like:

- replace tag and contents
- replace contents only
- remove tag
- change tag
- set attribute value.

The feature is described in the documentation[Set HTML rules for finding text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295353(v=expression.40).aspx) and has a well defined [Query schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa218656(v=office.11).aspx#odc_fp_extendfindandreplaceunderstandingqschema)

Do you know of a library that would implement the same features?

Specifically the library should implement as many of the "Find tag, Replace action, and HTML Rules" features as possible.

[image: Find and Replace Dialog]